# Recusos de una aplicacion en Java

Tags: java

Desearía saber como puedo determinar la cantidad de recursos que consume una aplicación en la cual estoy desarrollando en java.

Comment: ¿Por recursos te refieres a memoria RAM? Si estás en windows puedes ver el uso de la memoria de la máquina virtual de java (proceso java.exe) desde el administrador de tareas. En linux lo puedes hacer con el comando `ps` o con `top` si necesitas verlo en tiempo real.

Comment: Sobre el uso del disco duro, ya que se me está generando un problema de fugas de almacenamiento cuando realizo el test de estrés y estabilidad.

Comment: Si es un problema de almacenamiento en disco duro, ¿podrías dar más indicaciones del funcionamiento de la aplicación? Si es una aplicación que estás desarrollando entiendo que tendrás identificados los puntos donde se accede a disco. ¿Has añadido alguna traza cuando escribas a disco que te indique cuantos bytes has escrito? ¿Podrías compartir el código de las partes más significativas donde creas que esté el origen del problema?

Comment: Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para una MFP de Lexmark, la cual deberá generar un archivo log.txt en un servidor. Esto lo realizando mediante Streams. La generación de este archivo se esta ejecutando sobre un hilo

Comment: La pregunta parece basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias herramientas que te ayudan a monitorizar tu aplicación dependiendo en que te quieres enfocar, las dos que te podría recomendar según lo que dices es:

**[Java Mission Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr002.html#BABIBBDE)**

Es una herramienta ligera para monitoreo básico, mantenimiento y diagnostico.

**[Java VisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr010.html#BABEEIFH)**

Esta herramienta muestra información detallada acerca de las aplicaciones en java que están corriendo en tu JVM.

Si estas no son lo que buscabas prueba con el siguiente [listado](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr025.html).